# Ensure data is physically deleted from a data file

Tags: oracle

Consider the following:

You create a table space/data file for a table. You insert data into the table and this table has an index.

When you delete the data, it is possible that the data is not actually deleted from the data file. I wrote the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *file = fopen("/some/file/name", "r");
   int ch;
   while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
     if (isprint(ch)) printf("%c", ch);
   }
}
```

This will display any printable characters. I have found that sometimes the data still exists in the data file (on the OS level)

Is there a way of getting Oracle to zero this data?

Comment: Please tell me why the negative vote

Comment: [Related DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12958/847). As that says, you could update data before deleting. Depending on your version and licence, have you considered options for encrypting the data? (also see: [guidelines for securing data](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/keeping-your-oracle-database-secure.html#GUID-27A8C0A3-6DFD-4A0E-9FBE-772F867D6C91).)

Comment: @AlexPoole - I believe this does not work for indexes. Also trying to move to using transparent data encryption  I am also considering the ramifications of GDPR

Comment: @JoshParker Do you only care about the data files, or do you want all instances of the values erased?  Because erasing *all* traces is most likely impossible.  Aside from the data files for tables and indexes, the data could also be stored in UNDO, REDO, archive logs, temporary tablespace, flashback archive logs, and probably some other locations I can't think of.  Oracle goes to a lot of trouble to ensure data is never lost.  The downside is that data can be (temporarily) stored all over the place.

Comment: @JonHeller - Just the data files.

Comment: @JoshParker How many objects would you want to do this for?  Do you want to remove the data after every delete, or only periodically?  One possible solution would be to periodically run an `ALTER TABLE MOVE` to a different tablespace, with a different data file, and then shred the old data file.  But that would only work if this is done a small number of times for a small number of tables.

Comment: How about setting operating system permissions to only let `oracle` user ID read the data files?  And of course lock down `sudo` access to that user ID.